# debuging new caffe layer on nvidia nsight

Tags: caffe

I want to debug a new layer writing for `caffe`(`.cpp`, `.cu`, `.hpp`) on nsight, I'm wondering normally, would you wrtie a test for the layer and debug the `test.cpp` which has `main` in it and call the new layer? And should I write something similar to the layer test files in `caffe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely write a test for your layer, testing both `forward` and gradient computation (using the automatic numeric gradient test util).
Once you have this test it is straight forward to ascertain your layer works properly and if not it is easier to debug it without running the entire framework.

Comment: Hi! @ Shai, I see,  Is there a concrete instruction on how to write a `test file` and intergrate it into `caffe's` original `test_caffe_main.cpp` or if there is a way to run test for our new layer seperately?

Comment: @K.Wanter read the ["testing" section in this page](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/development.html)

Comment: thank you, and could you suggest a tool for debuging `.cu` file ? I tried Nvidia's `nsight`, but after compile I cannot debug properly, still finding the reason, seems not much docmentation about the IDE.

Comment: @K.Wanter I'm afraid I have little experience in that subject. I usually worked with simple layers where unit tests were sufficient to locate and correct bugs.